# int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter channel depth

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jdbc

if the configured channel in int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter is full,after that polling happens or not ?
Can I use a queue channel in int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter?
My requirement is that if the channel is full,no DB call should make ,until channel is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `QueueChannel` with restricted capacity. As far as any Inbound Channel Adapter uses a `MessagingTemplate` with the `sendTimeout = -1`, the `QueueChannel` performs a `put()` operation on the underlying `LinkedBlockingQueue`:

```
/**
 * Inserts the specified element at the tail of this queue, waiting if
 * necessary for space to become available.
 *
 * @throws InterruptedException {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws NullPointerException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
```

To ensure that the poller is blocked until space is available you should use a `fixed-delay` option do not allow any parallel calls to DB.

So, in other words so far so good as long as you use default options.